# How to bin values into positive and negative using the R package scales

Tags: r, gt

I'm trying to use the package `gt` ([here](https://rdrr.io/cran/gt/))  to build a table.  `gt` uses color mapping functions from the scales package to fill table cells based on values.  I'm trying to just get negative values filled red and non-negative filled green.  A simple example

```
library(magrittr)
library(gt)

column_one <- c("Larry", "Moe", "Curly", "Bob")
column_two <- c(-500, 30000, 0, 100)

dframe <- data.frame(column_one, column_two, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(dframe)[1] <- "Name"
names(dframe)[2] <- "Change"

dframe %>% gt() %>%
  data_color(
    columns=vars(Change),
    colors = scales::col_bin(
      palette = c("red", "green"),
      bins=2,
      domain = NULL
    )
  )
```

produces this table

[image]

I don't want the interpolated mustardy yellow...just red or green.

From the `gt` documentation

> The color mapping functions are: scales::col_quantile(),
> scales::col_bin(), scales::col_numeric(), and scales::col_factor()

Any help on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bins` to specify the cut-points you want to break the data in. Try :

```
library(magrittr)
library(gt)

dframe %>% gt() %>%
  data_color(
    columns = vars(Change),
    colors = scales::col_bin(
      bins = c(-Inf, 0, Inf),
      palette = c("red", "green"),
    )
  )
```

[image]